# Custom Post Type Template based on Taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, templates, taxonomy

I have a custom post type, Vehicles.  Vehicles have a custom taxonomy, new or used.  Naturally the vehicle pages use single-vehicles.php but I would like to differentiate between new and used vehicles by somehow using different templates automatically based on whether they're new or used.

For example, the New vehicles don't have certain attributes (Mileage, Year etc) as they're not relevant, so I would like to remove that from their template.

If this is possible, that would be great. If not I'd really appreciate any alternative ways around it.

Comment: You should really use post meta fields for boolean properties. Each post might be a member of multiple terms; in your case: a vehicle could be new and used at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to do this manually. You can put someting like this in your `single-vehicles.php` file:

```
if ( ... ) { // check if it's in used category/term
    get_template_part('part-single-vehicles-used');
} else {
    get_template_part('part-single-vehicles-new');
}
```

And then put new car template into `part-single-vehicles-new.php` file and used car template into `part-single-vehicles-used.php`.